# Page Redirect Not Working for mobile device

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that doesn't redirect when a mobile device accesses the web page. Where I'm I going wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var bodyclass = $('body').is('.index');

    if ((screen.width <= 800) && (bodyclass = true)) {
      window.location = "m/index.html";
    }
  </script>


  <title>screen stest</title>
</head>

<body class="index">

  <div class="style">
    <h1>index try10000</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe the mobile device is wider than 800px?

Comment: Maybe Javascript is disabled on your phone?

Comment: no my phone is less than 800 and js is enabled

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things, first are you sure your device is <= 800px width? Second your script is being loaded in the head and blocks the loading of the remaining DOM structure. As you have code that relies on the DOM being loaded you need to defer the execution of your script until the DOM is loaded. Wrap you code in a DOM ready function (example using jQuery).

```
$(function() {
    var bodyclass = $('body').is('.index');

    if ((screen.width <= 800) && (bodyclass = true)) {
        window.location = "m/index.html";
    }
});
```

Or better yet, just move your script to be the last element of the body. Then there is no need for a DOM ready wrapper.

Comment: thanks, but still not working, it only redirects if I use `if (screen.width <= 800) {
        window.location = "m/index.html";
    }` alone

Comment: Are you sure the `<body>` tag has a class index in that case.